# JQuery Steps Wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I am using [jQuery Steps library](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples) but my form structure is generated and I can't change it. I have a structure similar to this:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" id="form">
    <div>
        <div>some necessary content</div>
        <div>some necessary content</div>

        <div id="" class="wrapper" data-name="group">
            <div class="another-class">
                <label>Group</label>
            </div>
            <div class="some-other-class">
                more codes
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="" class="wrapper" data-name="group">
            <div class="another-class">
                <label>Group</label>
            </div>
            <div class="some-other-class">
                more codes
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="submit">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the problem is that jQuery Steps doesnt work with wrappers for title and content

```
$("#form").steps({
    headerTag: ".wrapper label",
    bodyTag: ".wrapper .some-other-class",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
```

here is my first attempt: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4bq5rco/) 
and also here is my second attempt: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cr89wvdp/)

So I want a step for each `wrapper` div with label as title of the step but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manipulate the DOM and elements generated with JS to give him the right structure.

```
// Insert new div contains your steps    
$('<div id="steps"></div>').insertBefore('.submit');

// Loop each step
$('.wrapper').each(function(){
    // Add to steps container, the title
    $('#steps').append('<div class="title">' + $(this).find('label').text() + '</div>');
    // Add to steps container, the content
    $('#steps').append('<div class="content">' + $(this).find('.some-other-class').html() + '</div>');
    // Remove useless code
    $(this).remove();

});

// Now, you have the right structure, you can fire your lib script
$("#steps").steps({
    headerTag: ".title",
    bodyTag: ".content",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    autoFocus: true
});
```